# How to add configurable product in wishlist in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

How to add configurable product option id in magento2 programmatically

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

> **scripts/addProductToWishList.php**

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$_wishlistRepository = $obj->get('Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory');       

$_productRepository = $obj->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');

try {
    $product = $_productRepository->getById('419');

    $wishlist = $_wishlistRepository->create()->loadByCustomerId($customerId = 2, true);
    /* config product options */
    /* 141 is Size attribute ID and 167 is Size option ID
     * 93 is Color attribute ID and 53 is Color option ID 
     */
    $buyRequest = ['qty' => 3, 'super_attribute' => [ '141' => 167,'93' => 53]] ;
    $wishlist->addNewItem($product, $buyRequest);
    $wishlist->save();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
     $product = null;
     echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I have create a api for wistlist .If i have to add the same product with option to wishlist for second time ,then I got the new product with same option for every addtowishlist